# How can I create this dropdown menu in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to create a dropdown like this image in WordPress Elementor. I tried so much but didn't find any solution to do this.

[dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gFyJ.png)

I checked many features of elementor but could not find this. Do I need to use a specific plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Elementor Pro you just need to activate Mega Menu to create something like this.